# How can I hide my shop cart in the menu with CSS on shop page only?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Hello community I want to hide my cart button ( already using it as SIGN UP icon ), I want to hide it on the shop page and probably other pages too.

I was using this CSS to hide elements on specific pages... example:

```css
.page-id-2615 #search{
display : none;
```

But on my shop page (Woocoomerce) the elements doesnt dissapear.

Here is the link of the page:

https://www.itshyfe.com/shop/

Hope that anyone can orient me on how to hide that specific element on the shop page

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I dont see any shopping cart icon

Comment: I change the icon, now is called SIGN UP, my mission is to hide that SIGN UP icon on the shop page, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide everywhere:

`.menu-item-cart { display:none}`

Hide on WooCommerce

`.woocommerce .menu-item-cart { display:none}`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOcbl.jpg

Comment: It doesn't work on this theme that CSS, anyway, Thanks for the answer and your wisdom

Comment: just add display:none !important